# Jquery show div for 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  $(window).load(function(){
  $("#loading").show(10); //it was hide but changed to show, not working


  <div id="loading">
  Loading content, please wait..
  <img src="loading.gif" alt="loading.." />
  </div>
```

how can I get this loading bar to show for 10 seconds?

any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You actually don't want to have a static fadeout mechanism like that. You want to know when things have finished and then fade out a loading image. Anyway for this specific requirement, see @patrickdw's answer.

Comment: Your question was already answered correctly, but I want to ask something else. What's the purpose of showing a loading-gif for exactly 10 seconds? Why don't you just show it while the loading process is being executed and hide it when loading is finished? edit: @jAndy: hehe, guess we just thought about the same thing...

Comment: buddy, why didn't u accepted any answer? Man....!!!

Answer (score 11):

If you meant that it's currently showing, and you want it to *hide* after 10 seconds, do this:

```
$("#loading").delay(10000).hide(0);
```

Or if you actually wanted an animation with the `.hide()`, add a longer duration:

```
$("#loading").delay(10000).hide(400);
```

Comment: @Ben: without the number passed in, `.hide()` would not get chained into the internal fx queue and therefore, the delay would get ignored. Thats what I meant with 'trickery'

Comment: @Ben: Because `.delay()` only works against methods that have been added to a queue. If we just did `.hide()`, the `.delay()` would have no effect. But if we give a duration, even `0`, it is added to the queue, and will be delayed. EDIT: Like @jAndy said. ;o)

Comment: @user892239 (if that is your real name): mark the response as the correct answer (tick next to the answer)

Answer (score 4):

```
 $('#loading').delay(10000).fadeOut();
```

If you dont want to fade out you can also do

```
 $('#loading').delay(10000).queue(function(){ $(this).hide();$(this).dequeue(); });
```

Docs:

- [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)
- [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)
- [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)

Comment: Ahh, I prefer your solution - much nicer :) - would be a +1 but as with patrick's answer, delay is set as milliseconds.

Comment: @Prisoner, Ben - yup, my mistake I updated this answer within a few seconds

Comment: @Jamiec: If you use `.queue()`, remember to dequeue it either by calling `$(this).dequeue()` or by adding a parameter to the callback, and invoking that, like `next()`. Otherwise the next time you go to animate the `#loading` element, it will still be waiting for the function to be released.

Answer (score 3):

```
setTimeout(function(){ $("#loading").fadeOut(); }, 10000);
```

Comment: setTimeout is so 2011, you won't even believe it.

Comment: @Ben: very naive. tell that to jresig :) http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=jQuery.fn.delay

Comment: Ha! Sarcasm never translate.. I meant to highlight the only example of setTimeout, where every example use delay :)

Comment: @Ben: Must remember to include the ES-5 `"use sarcasm";` declarative in your comment. ;)

Comment: @patrick. Touché. The funnier part is I even went to the jquery wikipedia page to check and pick a date that was before the official first release of jQuery (2006)

Answer (score 3):

Use Jquery [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

```
   $("#loading").show().delay( 10000 ).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#loading').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code...

```
$("#loading").show(10000,function(){
$("#loading").hide();
});

<div id="loading" style="display:none;">
  Loading content, please wait..
<img src="loading.gif" alt="loading.." />
</div>
```

this will display the div only for 10 second..
after 10 second div will disappear..