# Delay jQuery Ajax loader for 3 seconds after submit button is pushed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, loader

I'm  using a simple jQuery to show an animation DIV created with CSS after SUBMIT button is pushed. My issue is that when the server response is fast, the DIV is shown for justs some milliseconds. I'd like to display it for at least 3 seconds, regardless if the server response is fast or slow.

**HTML:**

```
<form class="search_cars" action="http://www.domain.com/searchresults" method="get">

    <label>
        <select name="model">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select Make</option>
            <option value="Acura">Acura</option>
            <option value="...">...</option>
        </select>
    </label>

    <label>
        <select name="type">
            <option value="" selected="selected">All Models</option>
            <option value="...">..models script...</option>
        </select>
    </label>

    <label><input name="zip" type="tel" maxlength="5" id="zip" placeholder="zip code" /></label>

    <label><input name="submit" type="submit" value="search" class="search_button" /></label>

</form>
```

**jQUERY:**

```
$(".search_button").click(function(e) {
    $('#loadingProgressG').show();
    $.ajax({
        success: function(data) {
            $('#loadingProgressG').hide();
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#loadingProgressG').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Looking at other threads at StackOverflow, I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189751/jquery-show-div-for-10-seconds) possible solution, changing:

```
$('#loadingProgressG').hide();
```

By

```
$('#loadingProgressG').delay(3000).hide(400);
```

But it didn't work. [Also tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307924/jquery-ajax-loading-display-the-loading-image-for-a-min-of-1-second) changing the same line by:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#loadingProgressG').hide();
}, 3000);
```

And nothing. The most probably is that I'm doing something wrong, I'm not a jQuery guru. Any help or advice is appreciated.

** I just noticed that using *setTimeout* works for the time set, only if some form validation stop the process.

Comment: You may need to post more of your code to get a fuller scope of what's going on, especially if you have form validation tied to it.

Comment: The form has 3 select menus (model, type, max price), and 1 input (zip code) and the submit button. I disabled all JS validations to see if there is a conflict among them, and I'm just playing with this LoadingProgressBar, it doesn't work anyway in whatever way I've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example should work. My only guess is that since you have the submit button tied to a form, it's processing the form as opposed to successfully running the function after the AJAX is completed.

In order to prevent the form from processing, you want to `preventDefault()` then run what you want to run.

***EDIT:*** Assuming that you need the form to actually process, you would submit the form after the 3000 setTimeout. Like such:

### JSFiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zsjL4/4/)

For the submit button, use a `<button>` instead:

```
<label><button class="search_button">search</button></label>
```

Then do the following for the JavaScript:

```
$(".search_cars").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = this;
    $("#loadingProgressG").show();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#loadingProgressG").hide();
        form.submit();
    }, 3000); // in milliseconds
});
```

Comment: Thanks jonsuh, it works, the loadingBar is displayed for 3 seconds, BUT it also prevents the process. The form doesn't work, it doesn't perform anything.

Comment: Do you want to process the form via AJAX or you just want a loader to show for 3 seconds when someone processes the form? We're assuming since you're using `$.ajax` you want to process the form via AJAX.

Comment: Really good question jonsuh. The form isn't processed via AJAX, I just want to show this DIV.ProgressBarLoader for 3 seconds when someone processes the form.

Comment: And also, hide the loader back if some validation is activated or something goes wrong with the form.

Comment: @JohnA10 Alright I updated the answer a bit. I stripped out the AJAX part since you're not using AJAX at all and instead just setting a timeout before the form processes and hiding the loader. I also updated it so you're using a `<button>` for the submit.

Comment: Thanks jonsuh for the <button></button> suggestion. I just tried the new code with out calling AJAX, and it is the same behavior. The LoaderBar is displayed for 3 seconds, but the form isn't being processed ''/ .

Comment: @JohnA10 Sorry, I'm not sure what to tell you. The JSFiddle I provided works with the example so there's something else going on.

Comment: GENIUS!!! million thanks for your time and patience, jonsuh. I didn't realize you had updated the JSFiddle... I had a very stupid and little mistake of just one character @-@, your solution is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to wrap $('#loadingProgressG').hide(); into a settimeout function.

Example:

```
setTimeout(function() {
$('#loadingProgressG').hide();
}, 3000)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed that sorry

Answer (score 0):

The page is loaded before the end of the JavaScript.

You have to prevent the default behavior. Use the function preventDefault() on your e object like this:

```
$(".search_button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        success: function(data) {
            $('#loadingProgressG').hide();
            $(".search_cars").submit();
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#loadingProgressG').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work in that way. I doesn't even show the loader. It also disables completely the FORM.

Comment: My bad, you should then submit the form in the success case of the Ajax. (ex: $(formname).submit();)

Comment: I edited my answer, feel free to tell me if it worked.

Comment: Thanks 317, the edited answer doesn't work. There isn't set the time to show the BarLoader for 3 seconds, and after pushing the Search Button, the browser doesn't do anything.

Comment: I think jonsuh's answer is now a better iteration than mine.